# When is :target computed?

Tags: javascript

At what point in loading can I use `document.querySelector(":target")`?

Given the HTML:

```html
<div id="target"></div>
<script src="code.js"></script>
```

The URL is loaded as `http://example.com/page.html#target`

And the script is:

```js
console.log(document.querySelector(":target")); // null
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", e=>{
    console.log(document.querySelector(":target")); // null
});
setTimeout(()=>{
    console.log(document.querySelector(":target")); // HTMLDivElement#target
},10);
```

When am I allowed to access `:target`? My workaround is `document.querySelector(location.hash)` which I guess works but feels silly.

Comment: Perfect, thanks @Quentin